# How can I retrieve the refresh token on the server-side using Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I need to implement a single-device floating license for my Firebase app, whereby a user can login to the app only on one device at a time. So, when the user logs in from another device, the other existing logins for this user should be invalidated.

Here is the flow that I am considering:

1. After login, from the client-side, send the Firebase *idToken* to be validated on the server before allowing access
2. On the server-side, use `verifyIdToken()` and retrieve the *refreshToken* for the user and store it
3. If the *refreshToken* has changed from the previously stored value for the user, invalidate the other refresh tokens using `revokeRefreshTokens()`

The problems with this approach are that currently, the *DecodedIdToken* object returned from `verifyIdToken()` in the Firebase Admin SDK does not have the *refreshToken* available. And `revokeRefreshTokens()` does not accept specifying which refresh tokens to revoke for the user. By default, it revokes all the refresh tokens for the user as of now.

Another point to note is that, although the *refreshToken* is available on the client-side in the *User* object, we cannot send this directly to the server-side as it can be manipulated on the client-side to send the same *refreshToken* from multiple devices, which would defeat the purpose. Better approach would be to send the *idToken* which has a limited expiry time.

So, are there any other alternatives / suggestions as to how can I go about implementing active login in only a single device at a time using Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a `refreshToken` from an ID token for the right reasons. Otherwise there is no point of having it, if it is retrieved from an `idToken`.

It is also difficult to implement single sessions using `revokeRefreshTokens`, as that will revoke all existing sessions and is more useful for protecting against token theft, rather than session management.

What you can do is the following. Every time an ID token is sent to your server, parse the `auth_time` from the decoded token and keep track of that (you would save the newest one). That is the authentication time for a session. All `idTokens` generated from the same `refreshToken` will have the same `auth_time`. You will always keep track of the latest `auth_time` and anytime you get an ID token with an `auth_time` that is older, consider that session revoked and block access to that session. You can return an error message to force `signOut` when that happens.